HTML <picture> tag and common "issues"
I am trying to figure out the usage of <picture> tag, as I have stumbled upon few non-working scenarios, about which I want to ask.
Here is a basic HTML


<picture>
  <source srcset="https://placehold.co/1200x800/blue/white" media="(min-width: 850px)">
  <source srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400/red/white" media="(min-width: 650px)">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/300x200/orange/white" alt="A description of the image.">
</picture>



This works as intended, src shows image, whilst in case of hitting required width via media switches the images.
However, changing media to (max-width) seems no longer to work and only the basic src attribute works. From my understanding, mobile first approach via min-width is preferred, but using max-width should work as well. Maybe someone could enlighten me what is going on and it's not working?
I have also seen examples with (min-width) em units, which I know what are for, but why would someone use those in this content? Are there any advantages in responsive approach in this context?
Lastly, even with the first working example, previewing this in Chrome dev tools does not work. The question is obvious, what is going on in this case?

I know picture tag is more optimized for web, but either I am missing something here, or its causing some issues compared to other solutions like media or container queries. Thank you in advance for talking a bit about these differences and usage of this tag.
I already went over documentation, checked few working examples, tried to replicate them, but the results were mixed. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.

There might be something with your images' linking. So, you have to check if, by clicking on the link inside the inspector, the image is opening in a new tab. If the image is not present as a preview, it's not linked properly.
And, in the max-width approach, you have to put the smaller sized images first in the order, and the larger ones afterwards, for the images to appear properly and gradually.


<picture>
  <source alt="medium" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white" media="(max-width: 650px)">
  <source alt="large" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400/red/white" media="(max-width: 850px)">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/blue/white" alt="A description of the image.">
</picture>



